# Express a set of non-negative integers in roster notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> **Question:** For each $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \cup \{0\}$, let $D_k = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup\{0\}: k = mn \text{ for some } m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup\{0\}\}$.

Write down each of the following sets in roster notation:

1. $\{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \cup \{0\}:n \in D_k \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup\{0\}\}.$
2. $\{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup \{0\}: n \in D_k \text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup\{0\}\}.$

My answer for $1.$ is the set of non-negative integers, but there are infinite elements, so **how do I represent them  in roster set notation?** Can I just write $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots\}?$

My answer for $2.$ is $\{1\}$. But, I am not sure if my answers are correct? Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notion of "roster notation", but the natural way to refer to the set of *natural numbers* is $\mathbb{N}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are fine.

For the first, since you want in roster notation, you represent $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ although this is the set $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}.$

For the second, your answere accurate, since $1$ is the only number that divides all the other non-negative integers.